# Is there something like template literals vice versa?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ecmascript-6

Using template literals it's very easy to produce something like this:

```
const age = 22;
console.log(`Paul is ${age} years old.`)
// => Paul is 22 years old.
```

While parsing information from text, I'm asking myself if there is any possibility or package using this principle vice versa.

Could be a function which retrieves the template and a string to match like this:

```
const template = `Paul is ${age} years old.`;

parseTemplate(template, 'Paul is 19 years old.');
// returns e.g. {age: '19'}
```

No need for complex use cases or type parsing.

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity - ``console.log(`Paul is ${age} years old.`)`` would log `Paul is 22 years old`.

Comment: thanks, I updated that

Comment: No, there is nothing, but you can relatively easily build this yourself if you use a normal string with some patterns that specify property names

Answer (score 1):

You can use [destructuring from regex match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_values_from_a_regular_expression_match)

```
const [, age] = /^Paul is (\d+) years old.$/i.exec("Paul is 22 years old");
// age === "22"
```

Notice that the first element in destructuring pattern `[, age]` is empty. That's because result of [`RegExp.prototype.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) is array and the first value is the matched string.